# React app deployment issue while deploying using github repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I was trying to deploy react app through github. After deployment, app page is not loading but in url I can see the favicon from public folder. also when I run same in local the browser open with my repo name like http://localhost:3000/groove3. what would be the reason? Please help

```
npm run deploy
```

https://anoop-acc.github.io/groove3/

Comment: Considering there is no console error it would be helpful to see the project or have a link to it.

Comment: Note the pop-up text if you hover over the [tag:git] and [tag:github] tags, that tell you not to use the tags simply because you're using Git and/or GitHub to store your code.